# Diameter Symbol not appearing in Layer Labels

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, unicode

I'm trying to label a pipelines layer with Diameter information. I'm using following expression:

```
u"\u2300" + [Diameter_cm] + "cm"
```

But Unicode (u2300) appears as a box rather than appearing as a proper Diameter symbol.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I'd use chr equivalent for your font.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create the symbol, using the VB parser as shown below:

[image: Example]

When you select the symbol from the Character Map window and paste it into the label expression section in ArcMap it appears as "AE" put when drawn its the circle with the line through it.

Here is the full expression, obviously replace the field with your diameter field.

```
"<FNT name='Symbol'>" & "Æ" & "</FNT>" & [PolylineID]
```